# Does DOJO components gets called automatically

Tags: dojo

I have these two tags for getting the Data from the server and setting it into combobox.

I have these two tags under the body of the JSP Page .

Please tell me whether we need to call these explicitly using dojo.addOnload or automatically the combobox is filled with data here ??

```
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" id="roleStoreId" jsId="roleStore" url="getData" ></div>
<div dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" store="roleStore" value="user.roleId" </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The components will be initialized automatically if you've set `parseOnLoad` to true in your dojoConfig.

```
    <script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true">
    <!-- or, if you're using an earlier version of dojo:
        <script src="dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
    -->
```